# mpirun error under crontab

Tags: mpi, cron

I am running mpirun command under crontab environment and got the error

> /opt/pgi/linux86-64/2013/mpi/mpich/bin/mpirun: line 75: /linux86-64/2013/mpi/mpich/bin/mpirun.args: No such file or directory

the `mpirun.args` actually is under `/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2013/mpi/mpich/bin/` directory. How can I let the crontab environment know where to locate it then?

Comment: What is actually on line 75 of `/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2013/mpi/mpich/bin/mpirun`? I would guess there is a env var that is not getting set when run from cron. As in `/opt/pgi` is all that is missing.
If this is not the case, you can set your path in crontab, as by default it is just `/usr/bin:/bin`.

Comment: hi, Timothy. Thanks. But how can I set bin path then? I set LD_LIBRARY_PATH for lib path already. I used export PGI="/opt/pgi" and it works. but I don't why it works.

Comment: To set the path in the crontab, edit your crontab `crontab -e` and then add `PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:XXXXXXX`. Where XXXXXXX is a path you want to add (`/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2013/mpi/mpich/bin/` for example). Once again, can you show us what is on line 75 of `/opt/pgi/linux86-64/2013/mpi/mpich/bin/mpirun`?

Comment: /opt/pgi/linux86-64/2013/mpi/mpich/bin/mpirun is the mpirun executable. Can not be viewed. I added the PATH but it is still the same error.